# Implementing infinite scroll with angular and elasticsearch via elastic ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, infinite-scroll, elasticui

Being both an AngularJS and Elasticsearch newbie, I’m currently working on a project where I should implement infinite scrolling on a frontend managed by [ElasticUI](http://elasticui.com) (AngularJS Directives for Elasticsearch).

ElasticUI provides a pagination object (euiSimplePaging) that allows to load results on separate pages, but I’d like to load the new results on scroll and add them to the current ones.

I quickly set up ngInfiniteScroll, which works, but I don’t know where to start to link both apps. In a future step, I would even be able to listen to the results before showing them, as they should be displayed in a masonry-like grid.

If anybody had a clue on how to get started…

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with ngInfiniteScroll, but I would try the following:

```
infinite-scroll="indexVM.pageSize+=10"
```

to increase the pageSize of elasticui whenever ngInfiniteScroll requests more items

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried, and it “works”. But that’s far from efficient. The whole results are loaded each time I trigger a modification of pageSize (not only the 10 next). I think I need to search for another way of *adding* results.

Comment: Makes sense, but that's not how ElasticUI itself works (it works with one "view"). You could add a collection layer on top of it which keeps the old items and adds the new ones as pagination info changes